# changing the 3D tick style of pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Consider this 3D plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-4.5:4.5]{(x^2)-(y^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: original result]

How can I alter the rendering style of the ticks so that

1. ticks are only drawn next to their labels, not on the opposite axis?
2. ticks are only drawn on the background faces of the 3D box, not the on the invisible foreground faces?

Here is the resulting picture I have in mind (I erased the unwanted ticks in the bitmap):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pgfplots supports only the small crosses; it has no builtin option to draw ticks in a different way.

Comment: Is this something I could hack in some way, or does it requires deep knowledge of the pgfplots internals?

Comment: Well, given enough skill and time, there are ways to modify that stuff. But it _is_ involved. 3D axes have surprisingly many challenges. pgfplots boils it down to pairs of main axis and the axis in which you'd draw grid lines, and combines these pairs in a suitable way. That combination comes with high complexity.

Comment: OK, so I'll keep the current style :-)  Thank you for answering.